# Rails how to display tabs with turbo-frame

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbo

In my Rails 7 app I've got `CustomersController` where inside there is show action with the corresponding `show.slim` view. Inside this view I want to have 2 tabs:

- "Data", with text of "This is data page" - this tab should be active after user hits show.slim
- "Customer Users", with text of "Here is the list of Customer Users".

When user hits show url (customer_path) he should be able to see Data tab as active and after click "Customer Users" he/she should not be redirected anyway but stays at the page and the text of "Here is the list of Customer Users" should be rendered. I want to use turbo-frame to control tabs switching, no extra JS needed. I'm using tailwindcss.

So what I did is that:

`customers/show.slim`:

```
div.tabs
  button.tab-button[data-turbo-frame="customer_data" data-turbo-frame-target="data"] Data
  button.tab-button[data-turbo-frame="customer_users" data-turbo-frame-target="users"] Customer Users

= turbo_frame_tag "data" do
  h1 Data

  p This is data page

= turbo_frame_tag "users" do
  h1 Customer Users

  p Here is the list of Customer Users
```

With some extra css:

```
.tab-button {
  @apply inline-block py-2 px-4 border-b-2 font-medium text-sm focus:outline-none transition duration-150 ease-in-out;
}

.tab-button.active {
  @apply border-indigo-500 text-gray-900;
}

.tab-button:hover:not(.active) {
  @apply border-indigo-500 text-gray-900;
}

.tabs {
  @apply border-b border-gray-200 px-4 flex justify-start;
}
```

Instead I'm getting this view:

[image]

Like I said, at the first glance I want to understand what should be done to make it work? It has to be turbo-frame because EOD I'll have few view components for that.

Answer (score 1):

Turbo works by making requests to the back-end, so if you wish to render tab contents in the same request, you would have to use javascript for the hiding & showing of the tabs.

If you do wish to use turbo, then you would have to change the way you approach this:

1. Since only one tab can be open at once, you don't need two turbo frames. You should have only one.

`customers/show.slim`

```
div.tabs
  button.tab-button[data-turbo-frame="tab_content"] Data
  button.tab-button[data-turbo-frame="tab_content"] Customer Users

= turbo_frame_tag "tab_content"
```

2. Create a controller action for each of the tabs

`app/controllers/customer_tabs_controller.rb`

```rb
class CustomerTabsController < ApplicationController
  def data
  end

  def customer_users
  end
end
```

`routes.rb`

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...

  resource :customer_tab, only: [] do
    get :data
    get :customer_users
  end
end
```

3. Add view templates for these actions, with a `turbo_frame` containing the tab content. When rendered, the previous contents of the frame will be replaced by contents here.

`app/views/customer_tabs/data.html.erb`

```
= turbo_frame_tag "tab_content" do
  h1 Data

  p This is data page
```

`app/views/customer_tabs/customer_users.html.erb`

```
= turbo_frame_tag "tab_content" do
  h1 Customer Users

  p Here is the list of Customer Users
```

4. Then, you have to add the links to tab buttons so clicking them will render the appropriate content.

`customers/show.slim`

```
div.tabs
  / To avoid having to specify `method: :get`, `link_to` could be used
  = button_to "Data", data_customer_tab_path, class: "tab-button", method: :get, data: { turbo_frame: "tab_content" }
  = button_to "Customer Users", customer_users_customer_tab_path, class: "tab-button", method: :get, data: { turbo_frame: "tab_content" }

= turbo_frame_tag "tab_content"
```

Now, clicking the tabs will open the respective tab content. To have the first tab load automatically upon opening the page, you would have to use [eager loading frames](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames#eager-loading-frames)

`customers/show.slim`

```
div.tabs
  = button_to "Data", data_customer_tab_path, class: "tab-button", method: :get, data: { turbo_frame: "tab_content" }
  = button_to "Customer Users", customer_users_customer_tab_path, class: "tab-button", method: :get, data: { turbo_frame: "tab_content" }

/ Will make a request for the data tab immediately and display it.
= turbo_frame_tag "tab_content", src: data_customer_tab_path do
  / The content that will be shown before the request to `data_customer_tab_path` completes
  p Loading...
```

As